# Cannot reset radio button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a web page for the mobile use, and I add a reset button to reset radio button but it not work. I have try to solve in many way, like

```
$('select#qty1 option').attr('selected', false);

$('select#qty1 option').removeAttr('selected');

$('select#qty1').children('option').removeAttr('selected').filter(':nth-child(1)').attr('selected', true);

$('select#qty1').attr('selectedIndex', -1);
```

but all of them do not work.

**Radio button**

```
<tr>
    <td><a href='#myPopup' data-rel='popup' class='ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext' data-position-to='window'>info</a></td>
    <td>Pizza</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>

        <select type='radio' data-native-menu='false' name='qty1' id='qty1'>

            <option value='0'>0</option>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>

        </select>
    </td>

</tr>
```

**Reset button**

```
<input id="reset1" type="button" value="Reset">
```

**script**

```
$("#reset1").click(function(){
    $('select#qty1').attr('selectedIndex', -1);
});
```

Comment: that isn't radio button by any means

Comment: If you can make the inputs part of an actual form element, using `<input type="reset" value="Reset">` will reset them automatically, without any JavaScript. And yes, that's a select element, not a radio button.

Comment: You should be doing `$('#qty1 option').prop('selected', false);`

Comment: `<select type='radio'` really?!

Answer (score 1):

1. there is no input type like that.

   ```
   <select type='radio'>
   ```
2. there is no "selected" attribute in radio button. use "checked".
3. you can reset radio buttin by " input reset".

   ```
   <input type="reset" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You mention a radio button but you are using a select box.

Try this

`$('#qty1 option:selected').removeAttr('selected');`

You need to specify the selected option.

Comment: None of the options has such an attribute though.

Comment: It will do when it has been selected

Comment: So, why does `$('select#qty1 option').removeAttr('selected');` "not work" then? (since `select#qty1 option` is a superset of `#qty1 option:selected`)

Comment: That also works fine [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kw8B6/)

Comment: It seems like jQuery does indeed treat `removeAttr('selected')` in a special way. But I think we have a different understanding what "reset" means. I understand it that the default value should be selected again. Your code instead will always select the first option, no matter which one was the default option: http://jsfiddle.net/kw8B6/1/

Answer (score 0):

this work.

`$("#reset1").click(function(){
    $('select[id=qty1] option[value=0]').attr('selected', 'selected');
});`